# fast retransmit does not work

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, ack

Fast retransmit says that if 3 dupacks have been received by sender, then the sender should retransmit the lost packet. But my tcpdump output shows that it didn't work like this. It didn't retransmit the packet even more than 10 dupacks have been received.
Why didn't it triggerfast retransmit? Does anyone has idea about this? Thanks

`cat /proc/version:
Linux version 4.2.0-42-generic (buildd@lgw01-55) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ) #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 20:22:11 UTC 2016`

`sysctl: 
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic`
[image]

Comment: In our systems, `net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0` and `net.ipv4.tcp_sack=0`

Answer (score 1):

Please check "tcp_thin_dupack"

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_thin_dupack
net.ipv4.tcp_thin_dupack = 0
```

```
tcp_thin_dupack - BOOLEAN
    Enable dynamic triggering of retransmissions after one dupACK
    for thin streams. If set, a check is performed upon reception
    of a dupACK to determine if the stream is thin (less than 4
    packets in flight). As long as the stream is found to be thin,
    data is retransmitted on the first received dupACK. This
    improves retransmission latency for non-aggressive thin
    streams, often found to be time-dependent.
    For more information on thin streams, see
    Documentation/networking/tcp-thin.txt
```

Comment: it seems that the tcp_thin_dupack is able to trigger fast retransmit with one DUP ack, so it can improve retransmission latency. But this seems can't explain why fast retransmit was not triggered with multi DUP acks.